# How to save command result in GitHub

Tags: powershell, github, yaml, github-actions

I want to be able to save the result from any command I run so that I can decide what I want to do next in my YAML file

Here is an example of a non working example of something similar to what I want

```
- name: Run script
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          status = script\\outputZero.ps1
          if: status == 0
              echo "output was 0"
```

I also tried doing this

```
- name: Run script
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          if: script\\outputZero.ps1
              echo "output was 0"
```

but it gave me the error The term
'if:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples from [Building and testing PowerShell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-powershell) rather use `shell: pwsh` (might be a synonym for `powershell`)

See for instance:

```yaml
  lint-with-PSScriptAnalyzer:
    name: Install and run PSScriptAnalyzer
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install PSScriptAnalyzer module
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          Set-PSRepository PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
          Install-Module PSScriptAnalyzer -ErrorAction Stop
      - name: Lint with PSScriptAnalyzer
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Path *.ps1 -Recurse -Outvariable issues
          $errors   = $issues.Where({$_.Severity -eq 'Error'})
          $warnings = $issues.Where({$_.Severity -eq 'Warning'})
          if ($errors) {
              Write-Error "There were $($errors.Count) errors and $($warnings.Count) warnings total." -ErrorAction Stop
          } else {
              Write-Output "There were $($errors.Count) errors and $($warnings.Count) warnings total."
          }
```

Note the lack of `:` after `if`.

- `if:` is a [conditions to control job execution](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-conditions-to-control-job-execution).
- `if (...)` is part of a Powershell script.

Comment: If I use shell: pwsh then my powerscript command just hangs which is why I decided to use shell: powershell @VonC

Comment: @DevopitionBro OK, but in any case, `if:` (with the `:`) is not a powershell syntax.